# Laravel. Connections between tables. Get the record

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, datatables, laravel-8

I used last laravel ver. framework. I can't get access to a certain record. I have two field links to one table.
My migration:

```
  Schema::create('application_forms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('clients_id');
            $table->foreign('clients_id')->references('id')->on('clients')->onDelete('cascade');
            
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('buyer_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('buyer_id')->references('id')->on('clients')->onDelete('cascade');
```

My model

```
class Application_form extends Model
{
public function clients()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }
```

I used on my blade

```
{{$application_form->clients->FIO_Client}}
```

But I can't access to record with `buyer_id`. I get record with `clients_id`. How I can get access to this

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('buyer_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('buyer_id')->references('id')->on('clients')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: Nope. I just don't know how to get access to "buyer_id" record on the blade.  I can get access to "clients_id" record by this way {{$application_form->clients->FIO_Client}}. I need access to "buyer_id" record

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the Buyer relation and model

Comment: Model is one it's a Client.  My model Application_form belongs to Model "Client"

Comment: Both client_id and buyer_id refer to client models? But the Application_form model only shows one relationship